# MySQL table design to store millions of Great Circle route distances

Tags: database-design

I have a MySQL table containing records for all commercial airports. Within that table I have the latitude and longitude for each airport. I plan to use a C# class to pre-calculate the Great Circle distance for many (or all) of those airports.

(There are approx 10,000 airports in the world however only about 2300 of them offer commercial service and those are my main concern. 2300 x 2299 = 5,287,700 rows. It would be a lot fewer combinations if I factored in actual route maps by the airlines but that's way beyond my pay grade!)

My question is how to (efficiently) design the new table which will store the distances. I initially thought in terms of a composite key which would be comprised of the pair of airport codes, but after learning that composite keys are order dependent I don't think there is anything to be saved by that method.

I visualize a simple 4 column table,

AutoIncrementKeyID - AirportCode1 - AirportCode2 - CalculatedDistance

Thanks for any thoughts or input!

-Mike

Answer (score 1):

Adding a surrogate key doesn't solve order concerns nor improve the efficiency of the design.  I suggest you keep the composite key, and add a check constraint to ensure AirportCode1 < AirportCode2.  This way, every pair of airports can only be represented in a single way in the database.  You could create views and stored procedures to enable querying and updates with unordered arguments, or just deal with the order in your application.

Comment: The constraint is a wonderful idea! Thank you! I will implement the table exactly as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

On further study I learned that MySQL 5.5 doesn't truly implement 'check constraints'. It parses them without error but then ignores them in execution.

However numerous people described using a stored procedure to cause an exception so the transaction is stopped. Here is the procedure I coded after reviewing several other threads here on StackOverflow.

I'm using a STRCMP function on the "NEW" intended values for the appropriate columns.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `chk_bi` ;

CREATE DEFINER =  `mike`@`localhost` TRIGGER `chk_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `Distance` 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN 
DECLARE msg VARCHAR( 255 ) ;

IF( STRCMP( NEW.dstnc_A, NEW.dstnc_B ) > -1 ) THEN SET msg = ('Unique Order
Constraint violated: Column A should always be less than Column B') ;

SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = msg;

END IF ;

END
```